# Contact Us Form Problem

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I've got a problem with Contact Us Form App. I've downloaded it from marketplace into my sharepoint website - looks like on the tutorial. In site contents the app created custom list called "submissions" where items should be created after clicking submit on the app. Unfortunately the list doesn't change at all. I've checked app permissions and everything looks like it should be ok, but it is not. Any help ?

Link to app and tutorial: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/add-a-contact-us-form-app-to-your-website-HA102845395.aspx#_Toc354573190

Comment: you found something?